# Storing React.js Components in a Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql

Me and my team are currently working on a project that allows user's to customize templates through dragging and dropping components. We will have a parent component that will encapsulate all the draggable and droppable parts. What is the best way to store the components with their styling in a PostgreSQL database so the user can come back and retrieve them later? They need to be stored on a database as they may need/want to access the same information and layout from a different system.

Is there a way to store React.js components inside of a database to retrieve them for later use?

Comment: If you can represent the components/styles as JSON, then it's easy - store the JSON.

Comment: @Adam If we go down this route, we will need something to reconstruct the JSON along with all it's styles on the front-end after it's retrieved I'd assume correct? Or is there some method/library that could do that for us?

Comment: There's no real point to say "if we go down this route". You are trying to store a representation of something - just as well to use JSON (plain text, do whatever you want). I don't know of a good open source project but you can take a look at this for an idea: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json. The hard part is coming up with a framework this is able to dynamically load and render components from JSON.

Comment: @Adam Thanks Adam, we will give this a shot and see if we can make it work!

Comment: It's better to check it out React Editable Editors. Most editors have its own data structure. And they show you a way with their structure that how to save your data in your database. Like `JSON`. Also, I recommend you **Prosemirror**.

Answer (score 0):

You can get html of a component and send it to your backend and store it as string there, when user comes back retrieve html related to user and render it.

Comment: Great idea (relevant link): https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate